# searchfield not working inside Controller

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, controller, react-hook-form

I have a multiselect Component which is have inbuilt search functionality like autocomplete component from material UI.
this component search feature not working under Controller. when I remove Controller its absolutely fine. I am not understanding what I am missing here

```
              <div className="mt-4 mb-4">
                <label className="">Region Access</label>
                <br></br>
                <Controller
                  name="regionIds"
                  rules={{
                    required: true
                  }}
                  control={control}
                  render={({ field }) => (
                    <MultiSelect
                    
                    // {...register("regionAccess", { required: true })}
                      {...field}
                      value={""}
                      handleSelect={(val: StringMap[]) => {
                        setOptionsBranch([]);
                        let branches = [];
                        for (let k = 0; k < val.length; k++) {
                          branches = [...branches, ...branchList.filter((dt) => val[k].value === dt.regionId)];
                        }
                        setOptionsBranch(branches);
                        field.onChange(val);
                        //setSelectedRegion(val);
                      }}
                      options={regionList}
                      variant={"primary"}
                      maxChips={1}
                      type={args.type}
                      selected={field.value}
                      loading={args.loading}
                      noOptionsText={args.noOptionsText}
                      deletable={args.deletable}
                      disabled={args.isEdit && checkDisabled("region")}
                      searchable={args.searchable}
                      searchType={args.searchType}
                      filter={args.filter}
                      clearAll={args.clearAll}
                      placeholder="select region access"
                      defaultLabel={args.defaultLabel}
                      optionLabel={args.optionLabel}
                      optionsType={"object"}
                      size={args.size}
                      countSuffix={args.countSuffix}
                      countPrefix={args.countPrefix}
                      style={{
                        width: "22rem"
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                />
                {errors.regionIds?.type === "required" && <small className="text-danger">region access is required</small>}
              </div>
```

I hope get a good solution